# Adding images to an array that is built from two other arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, blackjack

I am building a Black Jack game and have created the deck of cards, and the ability to shuffle the deck and deal from the deck.

```
let suits = ["H", "C", "D", "S"]
let ranks = ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "T", "J", "Q", "K", "A"]
let deck = []

function createDeck(){
    for(let suitCounter = 0; suitCounter < 4; suitCounter++){
    for(let rankCounter = 0; rankCounter < 13; rankCounter++){
        deck.push(ranks[rankCounter] + suits[suitCounter])
    }
}
return deck

}

function shuffleDeck(){
    for(let i = 0; i < 52; i++){
        let tempCard = deck[i]
        let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 52)
        deck[i] = deck[randomIndex]
        deck[randomIndex] = tempCard

    }
}

let shuffledDeck = createDeck()
shuffleDeck(shuffledDeck)
console.log(shuffledDeck)

function dealHand(){
    let blackJackHand = shuffledDeck.splice(0, 2)
    console.log(blackJackHand)   
}

function hitMe(){
    let anotherCard = shuffledDeck.splice(0, 1)
    console.log(anotherCard)       
}
```

I am unsure how to proceed with adding images to an array however I don't know how to add images to an array (deck) which is built of 2 other arrays.

I need to assign a card image for each card generated by createDeck().

Any advice would be appricated.

Comment: I think you can name your images names like H2.png, H3.png...C2.png,C3.png..etc for every card combination. So while iterating the deck array you can just access your card image by deck array value concat with image extension.

Comment: I advise you should rather create `css` classes such as `.skin-SUITE-CARD`  or `.skin-SUITE` and tweak the labels with javascript (or css with "content").

Comment: re: Navnath Jadhav - The deck array value is only the possition in the aray though isn't it? this would change every time the deck is shuffled. Or am I thinking about that wrong.

Comment: re: darklightcode thanks for the idea, I will try and figure out making this work.

Answer (score 0):

You can store cards as objects and deck will be array of objects(cards).

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.